# Moving a SQL Server database from Visual Studio to SQL Server Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've created a local database in Visual Studio 2015 and I need to move it to another machine that is using SQL Server Management Studio so that the TA marking my assignment can have access to it. What is the easiest way to move the database from one machine to another? I really don't want to have to start from scratch again on the new machine.

Comment: " I really don't want to have to start from scratch again on the new machine." - presumably you scripted the schema?

Comment: You don't have to move the db, just give access to the server running on your machine to the TA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking the easiest would be to backup the database from Visual Studio then restore it onto Server Manager. I don't use either so I'm not entirely sure how to do it for those specific applications, but you can always do sql queries!

backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE databasename TO disk = 'c:\t.bak'
```

restore:

```
RESTORE DATABASE databasename FROM DISK = 'c:\t.bak'
```